# In app billing - issue with managed item

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I had integrated in app billing within my project in order to sell managed item but I ve not really clear on thing. If user has multiple mobile devices with the same account registered for the market, every time user purchase an item, this item would be available on every mobile with his google account? Shall the Android Market notifies that item has been purchased on every mobile with user account registered?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes to both.

The following can be found under the heading "Handling refunds and other unsolicited IN_APP_NOTIFY messages" on the following page: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

> In the first case, your application may receive an IN_APP_NOTIFY
>   broadcast intent when a user has your application installed on two (or
>   more) devices and the user makes an in-app purchase from one of the
>   devices. In this case, Google Play sends an IN_APP_NOTIFY message to
>   the second device, informing the application that there is a purchase
>   state change. Your application can handle this message the same way it
>   handles the response from an application-initiated REQUEST_PURCHASE
>   message, so that ultimately your application receives a
>   PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast intent message that includes
>   information about the item that has been purchased. This applies only
>   to items that have their purchase type set to "managed per user
>   account."

Comment: "your application may receive an IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast". It is the "may" part that scary the hell out of me.

Answer (score 0):

android market also check device id of phone. so inapp billing depends upon device id and google account

Comment: I see.. any reference to this? Could point me to same kind of doc?